# Game slows down on click

Tags: javascript, events, canvas

I'm currently working on a game in node using socket.io and drawing onto canvas. I'm noticing that when I click during the game, character movement slows to a crawl. I would ideally like to maintain the draw rate that the game begins at and determine what's causing these memory issues. I'm looking to find out how I can debug this in a deterministic way

For context: I'm updating x,y coordinates in the game loop according to which keys are active (dictated by keyup and keydown events). I'm sending player information to the server via sockets about ~60 times a second.

To get more specific, here's a recording of the page's memory timeline:

[image]

The steep increase happens right around the time of the click event. The original jump (before the 6 extra listeners are added) is happening once the game starts. As you can see it's going a little wild on that click.

I have no handlers bound to the click event but the JS Heap grows rapidly and listeners seem to be added which confuses me. Here's a [link to my repo](https://github.com/aidankmcl/space-raptor-pirates), below is a chunk from `game.js` that has to do with keypresses and may be somehow involved:

```
var sendKey = function (activeK) {
  player.xSpeed = 0;
  player.ySpeed = 0;

  if (activeK[KEY_W]) {
    player.ySpeed = -SPEED;
  }
  if (activeK[KEY_A]) {
    player.xSpeed = -SPEED;
  }
  if (activeK[KEY_S]) {
    player.ySpeed = SPEED;
  }
  if (activeK[KEY_D]) {
    player.xSpeed = SPEED;
  }
  if (activeK[SPACE]) {
    activate(player)
  }
}

document.onkeydown = function(e) {
  if (activeKeys.hasOwnProperty(e.keyCode)) {
    activeKeys[e.keyCode] = true;
    sendKey(activeKeys)
  }
}

document.onkeyup = function(e) {
  if (activeKeys.hasOwnProperty(e.keyCode)) {
    activeKeys[e.keyCode] = false;
    sendKey(activeKeys)
  }
}
```

Thanks!

*Note*: I originally started from scratch to try to learn a bunch but will likely switch to a game making framework.

Comment: Could you post your code as well as all the libraries you are using (or a link to your project)? I find it hard to believe there is nothing bound to the click event and that it's causing that much of an effect. If that's the case, it's an interesting case to investigate - do you have a live demo?

Comment: Hi there, will throw this in a repo and edit the question when it's up, at work so it may be a little bit. There's a fair chance that it's just some weird little thing that I'm missing. Thanks for your interest!